# Oracle 11g Execute PrepareStatement Column Charset Problem

Tags: oracle, jdbc

## Env

- Mac Os bigsur
- Oracle 11g
- Jdbc driver: Ojdbc8-12.0.1 (thin) oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
- Jdk 1.8
- DataSourcePool: druid
- select userenv('language') from dual; return SIMPLIFIED CHINESE_CHINA.ZHS16GBK
- error msg : Occur errorcode SQL state [99999]; error code [17068];
- sql script:

```
create table WORKER_NODE
(
    ID          NUMBER(20) not null
        constraint WORKER_NODE_PK
        primary key,
    HOST_NAME   VARCHAR2(64 char),
    PORT        VARCHAR2(64 char),
    TYPE        NUMBER(11),
    LAUNCH_DATE DATE,
    MODIFIED    DATE,
    CREATED     DATE
)
```

## Charset

The server charset is GBK and client using UTF8 right now.

[image]

## Code

Here is my code, by using mybatis mapper.

```
 @Insert(value = "insert into WORKER_NODE (id, host_name, port, type, launch_date, modified, created) VALUES "
            + "(#{hostName},#{port},#{type},#{launchDate},#{created},#{modified})")
 @Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyColumn = "id", keyProperty = "id")
 void addWorkerNode(WorkerNodeEntity workerNodeEntity);
```

## Issue

I debug the driver source code. and I found it using **T4CConnection** to retrieve columns, and it returns unreadable characters.
The error occurs when the **PhysicalConnection** tries to execute getNewSql().

```
 public PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String var1, int[] var2) throws SQLException {
        AutoKeyInfo var3 = new AutoKeyInfo(var1, var2);
        if (!var3.isInsertSqlStmt()) {
            return this.prepareStatement(var1);
        } else if (var2 != null && var2.length != 0) {
            //Phase 1
            this.doDescribeTable(var3);
            //Phase 2
            String var4 = var3.getNewSql();
            oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement var5 = (oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement)this.prepareStatement(var4);
            OraclePreparedStatement var6 = (OraclePreparedStatement)((OraclePreparedStatementWrapper)var5).preparedStatement;
            var6.isAutoGeneratedKey = true;
            var6.autoKeyInfo = var3;
            var6.registerReturnParamsForAutoKey();
            return var5;
        } else {
            throw (SQLException)((SQLException)DatabaseError.createSqlException(this.getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 68).fillInStackTrace());
        }
    }
```

### Phase 1: doDescribeTable()

[image]

### Phase 2: getNewSql()->getReturnParamTypeCode()

[image]

I found the **tableColumnNames** were not correct.But I don't know how to fix this problem  **without change server's charset to utf8**

[image]

I have dropped the table and recreate it by datagrip. But it didn't work.
Please help me.

Comment: I find the problem occurs when PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql, String columnNames[])  invoked with oracle jdbc driver implementation

Answer (score 0):

## Problem solved, but why?

**When I change Ojdbc8 12.0.1 version to 19.8.0.0.The problem was disappeared.**

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
      <version>19.8.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

### Case In 19.9.0.0

Test Client and server charset are under the same condition.
[image]

But the kpcdsc return tableColumnNames without special character(like Id).

[image]

### Lower version [12.0.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1)

[image]

### Heigh version [19.8.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc8/19.8.0.0)

[image]

Are there any bugs that exist in the lower JDBC version?
Or any release note about the details from oracle?